# cURL 56 error on PayPal Sandbox

Tags: laravel, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to test PayPal sandbox on my local machine (Vagrant, Windows)

Why I initialize Express checkout it's works just fine, returns paypal_link.
But when I try to apply it I'm getting error:

`cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

The same script works fine on linux  dedicated server.
If there's no enough info tell me please what to provide, cuz I've got no clue why this is happening.

What also weird is that when I just refresh page, paypal returns an answer, but says that it's duplicated one.

Comment: Host must be reachable from outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal sends request back, host must be accessible from outside.